# Add query arg for pretty permalinks in wordpress way

Tags: url-rewriting

Currently I am using this-

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'download', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "download";
    return $vars;
}
```

Then this to generate url-

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
$book_download_url = $current_url."/download/{$value}";
```

Both the parts are working fine and give-

> ...post_url/download/42xcd

But I want to do the second part in wordpress way.

`add_query_arg` gives

> ...post_url?download=42xcd

from code-

```
$__new_url = add_query_arg('download','42xcd');
```

while I want to have

> ...post_url/download/42xcd

What am I missing here? Or any other approach? I tried `set_query_var` too.

Comment: have you tried this function ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: get_permalink gives what I am getting with current_url... I would like to know more if I have to use get_permalink without add_query_arg or when..?